# Zxing Xamarin Как включить фонарик?

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Делаю приложение сканирования штрихкодов. Использую Xamarin Forms Проблема с включением фонарика при сканировании. Кнопка нарисована, но как дальше её обработать я не знаю.

```
private async void ToScannerPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //await Navigation.PushAsync(new ScannerPage());
    ZXingScannerPage scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage(new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions { DelayBetweenContinuousScans = 3000 }, new ZXingDefaultOverlay
    {
        TopText = string.Empty,
        BottomText = "Автоматическое сканирование каждые 3 сек.",
        ShowFlashButton = true
    });

    scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        DisplayAlert(result.BarcodeFormat.ToString(), result.Text, "OK"));

    await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);
}
```

Comment: [Xamarin.Essentials: Flashlight](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/flashlight?tabs=android) ?

Comment: @tym32167 `using Xamarin.Essentials;` такого у меня нет, может что-то нужно из nuget добавить? я не нашел что..

Comment: без понятия, я просто загуглил ваш вопрос

Comment: @tym32167 попробовал этот вариант, фонарик запускается, но при открытии окна сканирования штрихкода он выключается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вдруг кому понадобится решение:

```
//сканирование штрихкода


public void ScanAsync()
    {
        ZXingScannerView zxing = new ZXingScannerView()
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            IsAnalyzing = true,
            IsScanning = true,
        };


        //промежуток между сканированием
        zxing.Options.DelayBetweenContinuousScans = 3000;
        zxing.Options.BuildMultiFormatReader();

        zxing.OnScanResult += (result) => 
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                DisplayAlert(result.BarcodeFormat.ToString(), result.Text, "OK");

                //добавление в БД
                BarecodeResult barecodeResult = new BarecodeResult();
                barecodeResult.BarecodeFormat = result.BarcodeFormat.ToString();
                barecodeResult.TextResult = result.Text;
                barecodeResult.Status = 0;
                barecodeResult.dateTime = DateTime.Now;

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(barecodeResult.BarecodeFormat))
                {
                    App.Database.SaveItem(barecodeResult);
                }
            });
        };

        var overlay = new ZXingDefaultOverlay
        {
            TopText = null,
            BottomText = "Автомаическое сканирование каждые 3 сек.",
            ShowFlashButton = true,

        };

        overlay.FlashButtonClicked += (a, b) =>
        {
            zxing.IsTorchOn = !zxing.IsTorchOn;
        };

        var cancel = new Button()
        {
            Text = "Отмена",
            BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand
        };

        cancel.Clicked += (a, b) =>
        {
            Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
            NavigationPage navPage = (NavigationPage)App.Current.MainPage;
        };

        var grid = new Grid
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        };

        grid.Children.Add(zxing);
        grid.Children.Add(overlay);
        grid.Children.Add(cancel);

        // объявляем элементы на страницу
        Content = grid;
    }
```